# Parakeet sudden death, trying to figure out cause

Tags: birds, death

My stepdaughter had a young (less than a year old) parakeet that was in a cage. She allowed her cat into her room and the cat toppled the cage off of her nightstand, making it flip over once with the bird inside. The bird got out of the cage and the cat had access to it, but we found the bird alive.

We put the bird back in the cage (stepdaughter was at work) with some food and water and assumed it was ok. We checked on the bird the next day to find that it had gotten out of the cage and was dead on the floor, across the room from the cage (several sliding doors on the cage were open about an inch, but were very hard to see that they were open). The cat did not have access to the bird at this time.

Could shock have caused this? Can a young bird last less than 24 hours without food and water? 24 hours would have been the maximum time.

Thanks for any answers. We're the parents, not the caretakers of the bird.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great chance that the cage toppling over scared your bird and even though at first, it seemed fine it could've had a heart attack. There is another possibility that after you set the cage upright and fed and watered the bird that once it got out it hit a wall or dresser to hard because it was just recently scared and might have resulted in its death. When you picked the bird up did its neck seem broken like its head was really loose and would move around easily?

Comment: The bird was across the room under a desk (the part where you put your legs), but certainly could have flown into something. It wasn't a great flier yet because it was young. Yes, the head moved around very easily, while the rest of the body was fairly rigid. Thank you for the information.